# HttpPostedFileBase siempre es null Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, fileupload

Aunque estuve mirando mucho sobre este problema en StackOverflow Ingles ninguna de las respuesta que encontré solucionó mi problema. Es MVC 5 C# y quiero subir un archivo imagen a mi controlador pero siempre me llega un null.

**Modelo:**

```
public class Img
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Imagen(Img data)
    {
        string response;
        try
        {
            var a = data;
            response = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = "Imagen: \n" + e.Message + e.InnerException;
        }
        return Json(new { respuesta = response });
    }
```

**AJAX:**

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("File", $("#fileImage").get(0).files[0]); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/Imagen",
    data: data,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:({ respuesta }) => {
        if(respuesta == "OK"){
            alert("Exito!");
        }
        else{
            alert(respuesta);
        }
    }
});
```

No utilizo etiquetas Form.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que noto basado en analizar otros ejemplos es como seleccionas el file desde jquery

[How to upload Image file using AJAX and jQuery](https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/)

Usar el `FormData` es correcto, pero que pasa si seleccionas el file de forma distinta

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
data.append('file', files);
```

Tambien que deberias validar es si recibes el file

[Multiple File Upload Using HTML5, jQuery Ajax and Asp.Net Web API – C# and Vb.Net](https://www.encodedna.com/webapi/multiple-file-upload-using-html5-jquery-ajax-webapi.htm)

para eso usa la linea

```
System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

en lugar de usar un modelo como parametro, porque puede que estes enviando bien el archivo, pero modelo binding de asp.net mvc no lo este pudiendo mapear al modelo que defines

Comment: gracias por responder!. Pero la forma en que selecciono el file y la forma que me has proporcionado ya he probado ambas, devuelven lo mismo pero ninguna funciona. Tambien he intentado esto `var hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;`, sin éxito. Lo he logrado hacer dejando de lado jquery y usando XmlHttpRequest solo cambie eso y funciona pero me gustaría hacerlo con jquery para seguir un mismo modelo en toda mi app